# Node js mongoerror 'write ECONNRESET'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When creating new document in **node js** gives MongoError of write ECONNRESET.
Following is **the error** in console when creating the new document:

> error: Error adding new agreementTemplate ! Error :
>   {"name":"MongoError","message":"write ECONNRESET"}

following is the controller function creating the error.

```
function addSubChapter(req, res) {
    logger.debug('Processing request for creating a new agreement.');
    console.log(req.body);
    async.waterfall([
        function (callback) {
            agreementService.getAgreementTemplate( callback);
        },
        function (data, callback) {
            agreementTmplService.AgreementTemplateSetDefaultFalse(function(err, result){
                callback(null, data);
            });
        },
        function (data, callback) {

            var agreementTemplate =data.result[0];
            var chapter ={
                         name: req.body.name
                        }

            agreementTemplate = agreementTemplate.toObject(); // swap for a plain javascript object instance
            delete agreementTemplate["_id"];
            agreementTemplate.createdBy= req.body.user;
            agreementTemplate.created= new Date();
            //agreementTemplate.Chapters.push(chapter);
            var chapters = agreementTemplate.Chapters;
            for(var i=0;i<chapters.length; i++){
                if(chapters[i].name == req.body.chapter){
                    var subChap ={
                        name: req.body.name
                    }
                    chapters[i].subChapters.push(subChap);
                }
            }
            console.log('----------------------');
            console.log(agreementTemplate);
            agreementService.createAgreementTemplate(agreementTemplate, callback);
        },
        function (data, callback) {
            agreementTmplService.addSubChapter(req.body, callback);
        }
    ], function (err, result) {
        utils.processResponse(err, result, res);
    });
}
```

When creating the agreement template it causes the error, here is **the service function**:

```
function createAgreementTemplate(data, callback) {

    serviceHelper.createModel(AgreementTemplate,  'agreementTemplate', data, callback);

}
```

and the createModel function is as follows.

```
function createModel(model, modelName, modelData, callback) {
    logger.debug('Creating new Model : %s', modelName);
    var modelObj = model(modelData);
    modelObj.save(function (err, newModelObj) {
        if (err) {
            logger.error('Error adding new %s ! Error : %s', modelName, JSON.stringify(err));
            callback(utils.handleMongodbError(err), null);
        } else {
            logger.info('New Model of type : %s created with id : %s', modelName, JSON.stringify(newModelObj._id));
            var result = {};
            result.status = httpStatus.OK;
            result.result = newModelObj._id;
            callback(null, result);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: We need to see the code you use to generate the error.

Comment: Well, you sure that mongo is active and listening to the address you pointed your code to?

Comment: yes, data retriving from db is successfull, but when create new record it gives this error